# React Native: onLayout triggered multiple times on orientation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

My app structure has parent container view > 2 Sub views.
The app orientation is triggered multiple times on first render and on orientation change.
What could be the problem? onLayout is attached to the parent container view